# Github Commit Branch and Pull

Tags: php, git, github, github-for-windows, github-for-mac

Just have a quick question. I have my master and I am committing to my own branch and
I had my co worker pull a fork off my master and he is committing to his own branch.

Now since I just did a final commit to my branch. Do I have to sync that to my master 
because, since my co worker forked my master and been working in his branch I need
him to pull from the updates I just did on my branch

What is the best way for him to do this? We are both using the GUI Github apps
he is on windows I am on Mac...

Thanks!
Ricky

Comment: If the feature you pushed to your branch is already done and ready for production you should merge it to master and let your coworker pull from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can push to a seperate server branch, and then your co worker can simply pull from that branch to get your changes.

for example, you could do the following (done in a command window, which Mac has, and something like powerShell would work for Windows):

you can create a new branch and store it on the server by doing the following

```
git checkout -b "nameOfNewBranch"
git push origin nameOfNewBranch
```

then your colleague can find that branch and pull from it (using a GUI), or could run the command

```
git pull origin nameOfNewBranch
```

when he/she does that, your changes will be merged to their branch.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My question is do I need to merge my branch into my master first and then let my co worker pull from my master.. thats where im confused

Answer (score 0):

As I can't "comment", i'll answer your question here.

No, you do not *need* to, if you do something like what I described above. In the scenario I described, you avoid pushing to master and instead push to a seperate branch which your co worker pulls from.

However, pushing to master and having your coworker pull from that is also an acceptable option.